# IconButton or any button not working inside a drawer header

Tags: flutter

I have a IconButton inside a  account's names property of a  UserAccountsDrawerHeader as it follows. The thing is that the onPresed behavior not works the 90/100 of times. I tried changing the button to an elevated button and so on nothing changed. Its weird because in some specific pixel it works. heres the navbar code. its an statefull widget

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
              child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(23, 72, 138, 1),
                ),
                accountName: Container(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        nombres,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 60,
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('1.');
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.menu,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                accountEmail: Container(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.030,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.home_sharp,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Inicio',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 21,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return HomePage();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.attach_money,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Estado de mi crédito',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 21,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Micredito();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.group,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Mi grupo',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 21,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return MiGrupo();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Charlas Educativas',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 21,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return TalkPage();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.send,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Enviar mi pago',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 21,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return ToPayPage();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Socio protegido',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 21,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: null,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.notifications,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Mis notificaciones',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 21,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: null,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.text_snippet_outlined,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Actualizacion de datos',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 21,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: null,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.exit_to_app,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Cerrar sesión',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 21,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                storage.delete(key: 'jwt');
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return WelcomePage();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` and specifically `accountName`.

It is probably built with some sizedBox or container which is covering your `IconButton`.

Since you are not actually using the properties of `UserAccountsDrawerHeader` I would suggest to switch to a simple `DrawerHeader` and the building the same widget with some rows and columns.

Here's an example:

```
DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(23, 72, 138, 1),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'accountName',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.menu,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.037,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('accountEmail'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks this has already solved the problem, next time I'd use DrawerHeader  to avoid this kind of trouble.